# For a group H the center of H is all a $\in$ H such that C(a) = H

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm not sure what the question is asking, can someone clarify

Comment: its not a question

Answer (score 2):

This would be clear to you if you "just read it in words".

You know the notation: $C_H(a)$ is set those elements in $H$ which  *centralize* (=commute with every element of) $H$.

Then (by definition) the center of $H$ is the set of those $a\in H$ *which centralize whole $H$* (i.e. $C_H(a)$ is whole $H$).

Answer (score 1):

$C_H(a) = \{x \in H: ax = xa\}$, in other words all the elements of $H$ that commute with $a$ (they may not commute with OTHER elements of $H$, but they might).

$Z(H) = \{x \in H: xh = hx, \forall h \in H\}$, in other words all the elements of $H$ that commute with EVERY element of $H$ (this may be only the identity, or it may be all of $H$, if $H$ is abelian).

You are asked to show that the set $S = \{a \in H: C_H(a) = H\}$ is equal to $Z(H)$. Can you do this?